# How can I track my location and phone logs?

Tags: sms, nexus-4, geolocation, call-history

As an experiment, I would like to track the following things:

- Location
- Phone logs
- Text messages

I have a Nexus 4 running KitKat (CyanogenMod, rooted), and I would prefer to export to CSV or something.

Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah. Some NSA app, uh, sorry, child-protecting monitoring supervisor app like [Parental Control Board](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.vionika.parentalBoard) might do that. But probably not export to CSV...

Comment: @Izzy hey, that might work.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: If it works for you, let me know, so I make it a "full-fledged answer"! I've never tested that app myself, though (but I have a bunch of others in my can, too ;)

Comment: @DanHulme "How can I export my call log, SMS log and location history to $format-i-can-use".

Comment: @Izzy we shall see, but I just installed it and I'm pretty impressed with the amount of data it's giving me. Location, SMS, calls and app installs/uninstalls. Fits the bill!

Comment: As you say it "fits the bill", I've made it an answer – so you can decide if it "fully fits" (and "accept" the answer), at least proves very helpful in your context (and upvote it), or both :)

Answer (score 1):

Android itself has no such features built-in (at least none I know that are accessible to the customer). But there are monitoring apps available targeted at "child protection", which can do most of the things you asked for. One example would be [Parental Control Board](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.vionika.parentalBoard):

[image: Parental Control: Position tracking] [image: Parental Control: Position tracking]
<sup>Parental Control: Position tracking (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

From the app's description:

> Parents can track all movements of their children in real time from web or from their own devices. At any point of time it is possible to get precise kid’s location.
>
> Parents can controls all calls made and received by their children, as well as all SMS messages, and set up Black Lists or White Lists of phone numbers for incoming and outgoing calls and messages.

Additional to your requested items, the app can also be used to lock apps not-to-be-used, and more. Not having used it, I cannot tell whether data can be exported to CSV, though.